# magento 2: quantity box and increment(+)/decrement(-) in product listing

Tags: magento2

My question is the following: How can I add quantity box and the increment(+)/decrement(-) feature in product listing in Magento 2.
I want my customers to be able to change quantity with plus minus buttons and order more than one piece from a product, when they are in product listing page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can, but this will be useful only for simple products (the only ones you can directly add to cart), since for configurable, grouped etc you will need to select some options.